# Javascrip count down timer: prevent reseting on page reload

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

I have a minute timer which counts from 15 to 0. I don't want to reset (= restart) the timer on page reload. but I can't figure out how to prevent the timer from resetting on a page reload. I'm using javascript with php. I have tried to add the timer time on load to php session but that didn't work for me. any suggestions? thank you :)

```js
function startTimer() {
    setTimeout('timer()', 60);
}

  var continueMins = localStorage.getItem("continueMins");
  var continueSecs = localStorage.getItem("continueSecs");
  
  if (continueMins == 'true') {
    mins = continueMins;
  } else {
    mins = 15;
  }

  if (continueSecs == 'true') {
    secs = continueSecs;
  } else {
    secs = mins * 60;
  }

  function timer() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
        seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
        progressBar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
        timerContainer = document.getElementById("timer-container");
        expired = document.getElementById("expired");
        btcAmount = document.getElementById("btcAmount");
        btcAddress = document.getElementById("btcAddress");

        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            localStorage.setItem("continueMins", getMinutes());
            localStorage.setItem("continueSecs", getSeconds());
        }

        var totalSeconds = 15 * 60, remainingSeconds = getMinutes() * 60 + getSeconds();

        progressBar.style.width = (remainingSeconds * 100 / totalSeconds) + "%";

        minutes.innerHTML = getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + getMinutes() : getMinutes();
        seconds.innerHTML = getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + getSeconds() : getSeconds();

        if (mins < 1) { 
            minutes.classList.add("text-danger");
            seconds.classList.add("text-danger");
        }

        if (mins < 0) {
            expired.style.display = 'block';
            timerContainer.style.display = 'none';
            btcAmount.text = 'Expired';
            btcAddress.text = 'Payment Window Expired';
            localStorage.removeItem("continueMins");
            localStorage.removeItem("continueSecs");
        } else {
            secs--;
            setTimeout('timer()', 1000);
        }

    }
}

function getMinutes() {
    mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    return mins;
}

function getSeconds() {
    return secs - Math.round(mins * 60);
}

startTimer();
```

```html
<p class="font-18 font-500"><span id="minutes"></span> : <span id="seconds"></span></p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make countdown timer not reset when refresh the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099714/how-to-make-countdown-timer-not-reset-when-refresh-the-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the localStorage (sessionStorage is also an option but more prone to restart your timer if the user e.g. reconnects in a new tab or restarts the browser)

 How to do it to be on the save side (crashes, unexpected bahaviour e.g.you should update the elapsed time in your local storage from time to time. The "normal" situations are handled by checking for the respective event:

```
var aTimer, bool;
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    if (bool) return;
    aTimer = setTimeout(function () {
       bool = true;
    localStorage.setItem("resetTimer", "false");      
    localStorage.setItem("currentTimer", MY_TIMER_VAR);
    localStorage.setItem("sessionDate", MY_NEW_SESSION_VAR);
 }, 500);
 return ; 
};
```

**EDIT** If you want that an elapsed timer is valid for lets say 24 hours you have also to place MY_NEW_SESSION_VAR which is a Date.now() converted in hours when reloading you check against TODAY_DATETIME_IN_HOURS which is a Date.now() converted in hours (This was my use case, if you do not need it just leave it out)

The keys and the values are always strings (note that, as with objects, integer keys will be automatically converted to strings).

 When starting your program (loading js) you should check for the vars with:

```
 var resetTimer = localStorage.getItem("resetTimer");
 var sessionDate = localStorage.getItem("sessionDate");  
 if (resetTimer == "true" || sessionDate > (TODAY_DATETIME_IN_HOURS - 24) ){ // start timer }
```

To delete a single item

```
 localStorage.removeItem("sessionDate");
```

If you want to use sessionStorage just replace localStorage with sessionStorage 
**EDIT** full code for the OP tested and working as asked

```
var countDownTarget;

if (document.readyState!="loading") docReady();
/* Modern browsers */
else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", docReady);
function docReady() {
  countDownTarget = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("countDownTarget"));
 console.debug("Initvalue: " + countDownTarget);
 if (isNaN(countDownTarget) == true || countDownTarget == "" || countDownTarget <= 0){  // If not defined
    countDownTarget = new Date().getTime() + 15 * 60 * 1000;
    console.debug("is NaN sInitvalue: " + countDownTarget);
  //Update the count down every 1 second
   setInterval(countDown, 1000);
    } else {
    console.debug("else Initvalue: " + countDownTarget);
    setInterval(countDown, 1000);
    }
}

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem("countDownTarget", countDownTarget);
};

// Functions you call
function countDown(){
    var now = new Date().getTime();  
    //console.debug("now " + now);  
    var distance = countDownTarget - now;
    console.debug("distance " + distance);
    var mins = distance < 0 ? 0 : Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var secs = distance < 0 ? 0 : Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);        
/** Add a zero in front of numbers<10 */
    mins = prependZero(mins);
    secs = prependZero(secs);
 // Output the results
    document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = mins;
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = secs;

    if (distance <= 0) {
 //   clearInterval(x);
    localStorage.removeItem("countDownTarget");
    clearInterval(countDown); 
    }

}

function prependZero(i){
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Copy between your script tags or load as *.js file

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but I still didn't understand. why are we using `MY_NEW_SESSION_VAR` and `TODAY_DATETIME_IN_HOURS`.

Comment: ADD the new code including minimal html to test to your question

Comment: Full working code attached see EDIT in answer- testing took so long had to wait every time the 15min.;-) Just kidding had to work and now the time.Look into it dont forget toaccept answer if this questionis solved Thanks

Comment: Are you clearing the interval with function name? because it seems when counter reaches to 0. it waits 15 mins to start again.

Comment: clearInterval(countDown);  its cleared - The code has no complete routine for resetting/ restarting etc. You have to clear sessionStorage manually if you close a tab/browser.As you did not like my proposal I wrote exactly what you asked for.